# How to include python files of Java project into .war with maven?

Tags: java, maven, jython

I have Java project made with maven. So I have typical maven project layout. And I use Jython.  So I got few python files. Wich I use through PythonInterpreter in Java classes.
I place my python files in src/main/py folder. And I use this path to import the modules by interpreter. It works fine on my laptop.

The problem is:
When I do mvn install, this folder does not goes to the war.
I read about maven resources plugin and added this folder as a resource. Like this:

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/py</directory>
    </resource>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

I that case it adds everything that folder contents, to web-inf/ directly, but not in the src/main/py. So that path is invalid for application in war archive.

Question is:
How should I place this python resource and what I should write in pom.xml, to be able to use the same path on the laptop, and the server?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try including  targetPath in the resource element as below:

```
<resource>
            <targetPath>../</targetPath>
            <directory>src/main/py</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.py</include>
            </includes>

</resource>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use the src/main/scripts folder and check if they where packaged into the war if this does not work check the documentation of the [maven-war-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/) and define it with the war [plugin as described in the documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html).

Answer (score 0):

```xml
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/py</directory>
    </resource>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

is actually enough to include into jar/war file.

For running see

[Compile Python Sources in Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52771221/compile-python-sources-in-maven/68495639#68495639)

It is not recommended to use `src/main/py` in your python script,
think as `src/main/py` as working/current folder for you python