# Compile Python Sources in Maven

Tags: java, python-3.x, maven

I have some python source files in my project (under `src/main/python`) along with java classes (under `src/main/java`). I would like to include these python files to my maven target jar. Is there a plugin available to do this?

I can observe that the build artifact created by IntelliJ does include the python files but the one created by maven doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, your current project structure has java files in `src/java`. This does not conform to maven standard. You should ideally be following the standard structure, makes compatibility simpler with IDEs as well as maven.

Java files should be kept in `src/main/java` that you want to package in jar.

Similarily, Python are just script files, not compiled. So you can put these files in `src/main/resources`.

```
src
|---main
|   |---java (Keep your java files here)
|   |---resources
|   \    |---python (You can keep you python files here)
|        \
|---test
|   |---java (Keep your java unit test files here)
|   |---resources (If you have any resources test specific)
|   \
```

If its not possible, you need to update pom.xml to ensure, `src/python` is treated as a source folder. Refer this plugin:
[build helper plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html)

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>add-source</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>add-source</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <sources>
                <source>src/python</source>
                ...
              </sources>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Python does not compile into intermediate files, but just executes `.py` files.
(Just like Node.js executes `.js` files.)

So we are talking about including and running.

`src/main/python` folder is not standard, in meaning that there is no plugins that would process python files. You can define it as

```xml
<build>
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/python</directory>
    </resource>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

Resources are just copied into jar.

To access the file from Java

```java
    private static String SOURCE_FILE_NAME = "main.py";
    private static InputStream SOURCE_FILE_INPUT = YourClassName.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(SOURCE_FILE_NAME);
```

For running Python from Java there are too many option, each with own limitations:

- as OS process
- as C/C++ library via Java JNI
- Jython (only Python, so practically outdated)
- GraalVM (as of 2021 experimental)

with GraalVM

```java
        Path path = Paths.get("venv", "bin", "graalpython");
        if (path==null){
            log("venv/ is not yet copied under target/classes/, run `mvn process-resources` or any next maven phase,");
        }
        //String VENV_EXECUTABLE = RunGraalPython3.class.getClassLoader().getResource(path.toString()).getPath();
        String VENV_EXECUTABLE = path.toString();
        log(VENV_EXECUTABLE);

        //try (Context context = Context.create()) {
        //try (Context context = Context.newBuilder(PYTHON).allowAllAccess(true).build()) {
        try (Context context = Context.newBuilder("python").
                allowAllAccess(true).
                option("python.ForceImportSite", "true").
                option("python.Executable", VENV_EXECUTABLE).
                build();) {
            context.eval(PYTHON, "print('Hello Python!')");

            context.eval(PYTHON, "import sys; print(sys.version)");


            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(SOURCE_FILE_INPUT);
            Source source;
            try {
                source = Source.newBuilder(PYTHON, reader, SOURCE_FILE_NAME).build();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            context.eval(source);
```

See https://github.com/paulvi/java-python-graalvm-template